# objective c arrays of floats and booleans possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, floating-point, boolean

```
NSArray chemConstantArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:0.0021400, 0.0012840, 0.0010700, nil];
```

Gives me four errors:

`Incompatible type for argument 1 of 'initWithObjects:'`

`Invalid initializer`

`Statically allocated instance of Objective-C class 'NSArray'` x 2

Which makes sense, as floats are not objects, but how can I make an array of floats.  I need one for BOOLs too.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519115/initialize-nsarray-with-floats

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need an array purely within your own code, you can use a regular C array:

```
float chemConstantArray[] = {0.0021400, 0.0012840, 0.0010700};
```

If you need an `NSArray*` for something, you need to wrap each value into an `NSNumber`.

```
NSArray *chemConstantArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0.0021400],
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0.0012840],
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0.0010700],
    nil];
```

You can use `numberWithBool` similarly for BOOLs.

Comment: Thanks - I used a C array like you suggested and used it by referring to `chemConstant[i]` where `i` is the index in my `for loop` building my `Chemical` objects.

Answer (score 0):

You want `NSNumber`, which can hold floats, integers, etc.